# My Scripts in cucumber is not working with appium server?

Tags: java, cucumber, appium

how can i solve this error

```
Failure in before hook:stepsDefinitions.setup()
Message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient$Factory;
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.<init>(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:93)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:95)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:94)
    at com.UK.BDD.cucumberFreamwork.steps.stepsDefinitions.setup(stepsDefinitions.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:60)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:224)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:212)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:202)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below my code is working fine for me. Please try if still if you face any issue then please let me know.

```
    public class Hooks {

private static ThreadLocal<AppiumDriverLocalService> service = new ThreadLocal<>();
private static ThreadLocal<AppiumDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
public static AppiumDriver getDriver() {
    driver.get().manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return driver.get();
}

public AppiumDriverLocalService getService() {
    return service.get();
}

/**
 * Start Appium Server Programmatically before each scenario
 */

// @Before, @After are called Global tagged hooks
@Before
public void startServer() {
    AppiumServiceBuilder appiumServiceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder()
            .withAppiumJS(new File("/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/build/lib/main.js"))
            .withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
    service.set(appiumServiceBuilder.build());
    service.get().start();

    if (service == null || !service.get().isRunning()) {
        throw new AppiumServerHasNotBeenStartedLocallyException("Nitin-: An Appium server node is not started!");
    }

    if (driver.get() == null) {
        setDriver();
    } else if (!new UsernamePage().checkForUsernamePage()) {
        //setDriver();
    }
}

public void setDriver() {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    if (System.getProperty("platform").equalsIgnoreCase("ios")) {
           capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
             capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, (String) CapsJsonParser.getJSONObjectValue("ios").get("platformVersion"));
             capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, (String) CapsJsonParser.getJSONObjectValue("ios").get("deviceName"));
             capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, (String) CapsJsonParser.getJSONObjectValue("ios").get("udid"));
             capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, (String) CapsJsonParser.getJSONObjectValue("ios").get("automationName"));
             capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.SHOW_XCODE_LOG, true);
             capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.XCODE_SIGNING_ID, (String) CapsJsonParser.getJSONObjectValue("ios").get("xcodeSigningId"));
             capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.XCODE_ORG_ID, (String) CapsJsonParser.getJSONObjectValue("ios").get("xcodeOrgId"));
             capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.RESET_ON_SESSION_START_ONLY, (String) CapsJsonParser.getJSONObjectValue("ios").get("resetOnSessionStartOnly"));  
             capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.USE_NEW_WDA, (String) CapsJsonParser.getJSONObjectValue("ios").get("resetOnSessionStartOnly"));  
             capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.UPDATE_WDA_BUNDLEID, (String) CapsJsonParser.getJSONObjectValue("ios").get("updatedWDABundleId"));            

             capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.BUNDLE_ID, (String) CapsJsonParser.getJSONObjectValue("ios").get("bundleId"));  
             driver.set(new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(service.get().getUrl(), capabilities));
             System.out.println("iOS device connected.");

    } 
}
```

Comment: iam using android and the target is integrate the TestNG with cucumber to able to read the capability from the parameter file

Comment: @Menna have you used same as I mentioned above code?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you don't use any `selenium` dependency as appium `java-client` comes with selenium and then invalidate/clear your cache and restart your IDE

This dependency is enough.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
  <version>versionYouNeed</version>
</dependency>
```